# iRecords variable no change after execute DbiWriteBlock function

Tags: delphi, bde

The value of iRecords variable no change after execute DbiWriteBlock function. Please explain this to me. Thanks!

This is my code:

```
procedure TMainForm.btnBDICheckClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Table       : TTable;
  PTable      : PByte;
  RecordSize  : Integer;
  RecordCount : Integer;
  iRecords    : Integer;
begin
  Table              := TTable.Create(Self);
  Table.DatabaseName := 'D:\Temp';
  Table.TableName    := 'SrcTable.db';
  Table.Active       := True;

  RecordSize  := Table.RecordSize;
  RecordCount := Table.RecordCount;

  PTable   := nil;
  iRecords := 0;

  GetMem(PTable, RecordSize * RecordCount);
  DbiWriteBlock(Table.Handle, iRecords, PTable);

  // iRecords = 0 at here

  Table.Close;
end;
```

Comment: The BDE APIs are deprecated, buggy, poorly documented and closed source.  I am not aware of any documentation to cover this. Assuming here that iRecords is  a var parameter you may have then assumed it should be set?  Is that your issue? Or that the write didn't work? (The paradox table was not written to.)

Why you want to write new code using the BDE in 2018?

Comment: @WarrenP:
- I have a delphi source code use BDE, and I want to migrate it to ADO. So, I must understand DbiWriteBlock method (input, processing, output).
- I debug, and see the value of iRecords (var) no change, and source code no error, table is valid.

Comment: I don't think you  MUST use an undocument (possibly broken) API call to migrate off BDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `iRecords` is a pointer to the number of records to be written. On output, `iRecords` will have the actual number of records written. Your code should look like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.btnBDICheckClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Table       : TTable;
  PTable      : PByte;
  RecordSize  : Integer;
  RecordCount : Integer;
  iRecords    : Integer;
begin
   Table              := TTable.Create(Self);
   Table.DatabaseName := 'D:\Temp';
   Table.TableName    := 'SrcTable.db';
   Table.Active       := True;

   RecordSize  := Table.RecordSize;
   RecordCount := Table.RecordCount;

   //PTable   := nil;
   //iRecords := 0;

   iRecords := RecordCount;
   GetMem(PTable, RecordSize * RecordCount);
   DbiWriteBlock(Table.Handle, iRecords, PTable);

   Table.Close;
   ShowMessage('Records: ' + IntToStr(iRecords));
end;
```

With this code you will add empty records. Use `DbiInitRecord()` and `DbiPutField()` to fill field values.

Below is the documentation about the `DbiWriteBlock` function (from BDE help file):

> **Function definition:**
>
> ```
> function DbiWriteBlock (hCursor: hDBICur; var iRecords: Longint; pBuf: Pointer): DBIResult stdcall;
> ```
>
> **Description:**
>
> DbiWriteBlock writes a block of records to the table associated with
> hCursor.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> hCursor Type: hDBICur (Input) Specifies the cursor handle to the table.
> piRecords Type: pUINT32 (Input/Output) On input, piRecords is a pointer to the number of records to write. On output, pointer to the client variable that receives the actual number of records written. The number actually written may be less than requested if an integrity violation or other error occurred.
> pBuf Type: pBYTE (Input) Pointer to the buffer containing the records to be written.
> ```
>
> **Usage:**
>
> This function is similar to calling DbiAppendRecord for the specified
> number of piRecords. DbiWriteBlock can access data in blocks larger
> than 64Kb, depending on the size you allocate for the buffer.
>
> **Note:**
>
> This function cannot be used if the records contain non-empty BLOBs.
>
> **Paradox:**
>
> This function verifies any referential integrity requirements or
> validity checks that may be in place. If either fails, the write
> operation is canceled.
>
> **Completion state:**
>
> The cursor is positioned at the last record that was inserted.
>
> **Result:**
>
> ```
> DbiResult                   Meaning
> DBIERR_NONE                 The block of records contained in pBuf has been successfully written to the table specified by hCursor.
> DBIERR_INVALIDHNDL          The specified cursor handle is invalid or NULL, or piRecords is NULL, or pBuf is NULL.
> DBIERR_TABLEREADONLY        The table is opened read-only; cannot write to it.
> DBIERR_NOTSUFFTABLERIGHTS   Insufficient table rights to insert a record. (Paradox only.)
> DBIERR_NODISKSPACE          Insertion failed due to insufficient disk space.
> ```
>
> **Example from Delphi 7 help:**
>
> ```
> procedure fDbiWriteBlock(Customer: TTable; var RecordsToInsert: Longint);
>
> var
>   pRecordsBuf, pTmpBuf: pBYTE;
>   Rec: Longint;
>   CustNo: Double;
> begin
>   Randomize;
>   GetMem(pRecordsBuf, Customer.RecordSize * RecordsToInsert);
>   pTmpBuf := pRecordsBuf;
>   try
>     for Rec := 1 to RecordsToInsert do begin
>       CustNo := Random(1000000);
>       // Iterate through the entire record buffer filling each
>       // individual record with information
>       with Customer do begin
>         Check(DbiInitRecord(Handle, pTmpBuf));
>
>         Check(DbiPutField(Handle, FieldByName('CustNo').Index + 1, pTmpBuf,
>           pBYTE(@CustNo)));
>         Check(DbiPutField(Handle, FieldByName('Company').Index + 1, pTmpBuf,
>           PChar('INPRISE Corporation')));
>         Inc(pTmpBuf, RecordSize);
>       end;
>     end;
>     Check(DbiWriteBLock(Customer.Handle, RecordsToInsert, pRecordsBuf));
>   finally
>     FreeMem(pRecordsBuf, Customer.RecordSize * RecordsToInsert);
>   end;
> end
> ```